# focus with textarea but cursor invisualable

Tags: jquery

I tried to get focus after a node is insert after:

```
<p>Insert new content</p>

var footnoteForm = $(`
<form class="article-footnote-form footnote-form" style="margin-top:10px">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="footnote" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="articleFootnoteBtn">Add Annotation</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>`);
//insert after
$("p").after(footnoteForm);
```

When I test on console to get focus, the cursor not emerges in textarea:

```
$("textarea :first").focus()
jQuery.fn.init [textarea.form-control, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$('textarea:first').focus()` w/o space in selector. `textarea :first` means `textarea *:first` - selects first nested element within textarea.

```js
var footnoteForm = $(`
    <form class="article-footnote-form footnote-form" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="footnote" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="articleFootnoteBtn">Add Annotation</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    </form>`);
//insert after
$("p").after(footnoteForm);

$('textarea:first').focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Insert new content</p>
```